# Step by step process to overcome selinux denial

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, selinux

I am running an apk well on the emulator. When I run the apk on a real device, it works well. However, in some instances and for a strange reason on the real device, it throws the following error;

**avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=10037 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0......**

I have done some research and from the various solutions, I can tell that the exception is caused by **scontext=u:r:untrusted_app** as indicated in the error above. Most of solutions offered have not been fruitful with some just leaving it at "use audit2allow" with no clear explanation of a step by step of how to use the proposed audit2allow.

Any solutions are invited

Comment: I suggest you start by running `audit2allow -w -a` for explanation. https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow

Comment: @EricLavault looks like those are linux commands. I'm using windows

Comment: SELinux, which means Security Enhanced Llinux, runs on android, which is derived from linux, so in your emulator you should be able to run these commands. https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate

Comment: @EricLavault I now get you. However, like I stated above, the error only occurs on real device. not the emulator. Is there a way to run the commands on a real device?

Comment: Yes you can run commands via adb, cf. [`adb shell`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#shellcommands) commands, or directly in a terminal on your phone if rooted.

Comment: @EricLavault thanks, I'll give that a try. Thanks for your explanation